# How can I display "read more" without any other post text?

Tags: the-content, read-more

I have created the **Read more** in my posts, but when I add the php tag

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

...it shows the post content with **read more** button. I only want to display the button, with no post content.

Here is a picture of my design .[image: Desired design]

In the picture, I only display the button without text from the post.
How can i do that with WordPress php code?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with many ways. First thing you need to use

```
the_excerpt()
```

instead of

```
the_content()
```

and in your functions.php file you can add this function to return 0 text from post text.

```
function custom_excerpt_length($length) {
    if (is_home()) {
        return 0;
    }
}

add_filter('excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length');
```

This code check if this is homepage you can change the condition to met your needs.

Comment: up vote our teacher :)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Osama, I changed the function and its working but still cant view the full post or the single post while clicking on the **read more** button, i used the tag ` the_permalink()` but its not working. any suggestion please.

Comment: show me your code please to see why permalink not work and BTW i give this function so you can use this template in other pages and change the excerpt length as you need that's why i didn't told you to use only the_permalink()

Answer (score 0):

If you JUST need the button, there's probably a different way to go about this:

`<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="your-button-class">Read More</a>`

Only loads what you need (the permalink) and doesn't bother with extra functions, excerpt length, etc.